# How to implement a Stripe Payment system for one-time payments and free re-signups

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I created a notification service that emails customers. I want to implement a payment system where the customer can re-sign to be notified for the same thing without having to pay twice. Is this possible through Stripe?

Comment: That check would be on your end, not theirs.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to implement this check? Could it involve something like a JWT token that checks if the user has already paid. I'm not sure what the best approach is

Comment: You presumably store some sort of database record about each customer. Store the fact that they've paid in there.